# Output of terminal to a csv with separate columns in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, export-to-csv

my code goes as follows:

```
import csv
with open('Remarks_Drug.csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    for row in reader:
        product = row[0].lower()
        filename = row[1]
        product_patterns = ', '.join([i.split("+")[0].strip() for i in product.split(",")])
        print(product_patterns, filename)
```

which outputs as below: (where film-coated tab should be one column and the filename should be another column)

```
film-coated tablet RECD outcome AUBAGIO IAIN-21 AoR.txt
solution for injection 093 Acceptance NO Safety profil.txt
```

I want to output this to a csv file with one column as product_patterns and another as filename. I wrote the below code but only the last row gets appended. Can anyone please help me with the looping here. The code I wrote is:

```
with open ('drug_output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['product_patterns', 'filename']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({'product_patterns':product_patterns, 'filename':filename})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkpEA.png)

Comment: Remarks_Drug.csv give this file content

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: you facing issue may be because you looping on files line by line and adding only last element to output file just create two separate arrays and save data into then then add it to dict

Comment: The csv contains product names in the first column and matching filenames in the next column:  example:  lies in the 2nd code block in the example

Comment: csv has been attached

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the environment that you can use, it might be more practical to use more dedicated programs to solve your problem.

Especially the [pandas package](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/#) seems useful in your case.
Then you can load the csv using:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

After doing the necessary manipulations, you can save it again with

```
df.to_csv(file_path)
```

This will save you a lot of issues that typically occur when parsing line by line, and it should also increase performance a bit. Pandas is a pretty good package to learn anyway if you need to do some data manipulation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the csv and the desired output then?

Comment: Csv example has been provided. desired output is just the same csv stripped of all characters after '+' character